# Why String's replaceAll() method come at high performance cost at the first time and faster at the next time?

Tags: java, regex, string, optimization

I've learned that `String's replaceAll()` method takes a regex as an input parameter and it can cause considerable performance impact. But once time, I read this [blog](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-regular-expressions/performance.html) with a small program assert that (according my understanding):

> Process the `replaceAll()` method slow for the first time but faster for the next time.

This is test result:

```
regex replace time taken: 14.09 milliseconds
manual replace time taken: 2.371 seconds
-----
regex replace time taken: 9.498 milliseconds
manual replace time taken: 2.406 seconds
-----
regex replace time taken: 2.184 milliseconds
manual replace time taken: 2.360 seconds
-----
```

What is the optimization mechanism behind this result?

Answer (score 4):

Usually it doesn't cause a *meaningful* performance impact unless used in weird and unusual ways. In a normal use case (let's say web request) it will disappear under things like network latency and other things that take way more time. Only if you were to use `replaceAll` in a very hot loop, would it become necessary to consider using the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes directly, which could help with performance.

The linked tutorial site seems questionable (and there are a lot of them, which is why you should be careful what you read). For one, it compares `replaceAll` with a manual replace method that is poorly written (that's why you get the seconds vs. milliseconds difference). Then it draws conclusions based on that.

So there's no optimization mechanism behind the result in the link. The reason behind the result is the badly written manual replacement method which concatenates a lot of Strings, making it slow compared to `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 4):

The following is taken from the official<sup>1</sup> OpenJDK 11 source code<sup>2</sup>.

Starting with the `String.replaceAll` method itself.

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement);
}
```

No caching here.  Next the `Pattern.compile`

```
public static Pattern compile(String regex) {
    return new Pattern(regex, 0);
}
```

No caching there either.  And not in the private `Pattern` constructor either.

The `Pattern` constructor uses an internal `compile()` method to do the working of compiling the regex to the internal form.  It takes steps to avoid a `Pattern` being compiled twice.  But as you can see from the above, each `replaceAll` call is generating a single use `Pattern` object.

So why are you seeing a speedup in those performance figures?

- They could be using an old version (before Java 6) of `Pattern` that might have<sup>3</sup> cached compiled patterns.
- The most likely explanation is that this just a JVM warmup effect.  A well written benchmark *should* account for that, but the benchmark that is used in that blog is not doing proper warmup.

In short, the speedup that you think is caused by some "optimization" is apparently just the result of JVM warmup effects such as JIT compilation of the `Pattern`, `Matcher` and related classes.

---

<sup>1 - The OpenJDK source code for Java 6 onwards is can be downloaded from https://openjdk.java.net/</sup>

<sup>2 - The OpenJDK 6 source code is doing the same thing: no caching.</sup>

<sup>3 - I have not checked, but it is moot. Performance benchmarks based on EOL versions of Java are not instructive for current versions of Java.  Nobody should still be using Java 5.  If they are, performance of `replaceAll` is the least of their worries.</sup>

Comment: `The OpenJDK 6 source code is doing the same thing: no caching.` >> Is there any official document about this citation? @Stephen C

Comment: The source code itself is an official document.  I have even quoted from it!  AFAIK, there is no official *specification* that says that Patterns are cached or not.  The *evidence* from the actual implementation (multiple versions) is that there is no caching.  (At least, none relevant to this example.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you execute replaceAll over the same expression again and again, then the matched chars are indeed less frequents, so fewer replacements.

Example : /(.)(.*?)\1/ matches strings with a repeated char, and replaceAll matches with $2 will remove these duplicate chars, but it needs to be execute multiple times to process all the duplicates (there can be some in $2 for example)

- ABCDEFABCBCDEF for example gives BCDEFCCDEF
- BCDEFCCDEF ==> BDEFCDEF
- BDEFCDEF ==> BEFCEF
- BEFCEF ==> BFCF
- BFCF ==> BC

The processed string is smaller and smaller, the match count gets lower and lower, so processing time decreases as well.

I admit that this answer is really specific to a use-case, but I cannot reproduce the behavior you mentioned so it has to be somehow specific to a use-case.

Caching can also be a reason - I first read 14 *seconds* instead of milliseconds - but mixing units like this isn't a brilliant idea either...

Answer (score 0):

Well, replaceAll uses regex internally will compile each time you call it, but possible if we execute replaceAll over the same expression again and again java use some internal mechanism so that same expression will not compile again and make the repetitive replacement faster or just a JIT effect.